# Insert random digits into a column using sql only (Laravel)?

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to fill on columns with random values  between 2 ranges

I got this query

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO table(table_id) VAlUES(ELT(0.5 + RAND() * 100));
```

Is that possible to do using laravel ??

I want to insert random values using sql only  since php will make it very slow

comparing to sql only

Comment: Sure, you'll just have to use `DB::statement()` instead of using the query builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use query builder and Raw expressions

```
DB::table('table')->insert(
   ['table_id' => DB::raw("ELT(0.5 + RAND() * 100))")]
);
```

Comment: You can use query builder inside insert function   anyway I will try it